# SPOJ - INUMBER (Can't seem to develop a solution within the time limit)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem on SPOJ [INUMBER](http://www.spoj.com/problems/INUMBER/). 
**Problem statement** is as follows:

For the given number `n` find the minimal positive integer divisable by `n`, with the sum of digits equal to `n`.

**INPUT**

`t` – the number of test cases, then t test cases follow. `(t <= 50)` 
Test case description: 
`n` - integer such that `0 < n <= 1000`

**OUTPUT** 
 
 For each test case output the required number (without leading zeros).

**EXAMPLE:**

```
Input:
2
1
10

Output:
1
190
```

I can only think of a brute force solution emulating the number digit by digit from 0-9 and forming a dfs structure and repeatedly checking whether it's divisible by n or not.

Before asking my question here, I did a meticulous search on this problem on the internet and couldn't found any detailed explanation. Most of them were undocumented raw code and others were giving just a jist of the solution. 
I'm really interested in solving this problem not just for the points but to learn something new.

Thanks for the help Stackoverflow community :)

Comment: Since `n <= 1000`, you could always precompute all `1000` outcomes and just do a lookup. No need to worry about the time limit anymore ;-)

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele: I guess that's the crux of the problem to solve it for any N. Can you please give me more insight on your dynamic programming approach. :)

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele the linked problem has a source limit of only 4kB.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a breadth first search.

Let `num(p, q)` be the minimum number of digits with digit sum `p` and remainder mod `n` equal to `q`.

We want to find `num(n, 0)`. Then, we can greedily build the smallest such number.

We start from the state `(0, 0)`. From a state `(x, y)` you can get to a state:

```
(x + j, (y * 10 + j) % n)
```

for each digit `j`.

Keep track of each digit `j` you add and then backtrack from `(n, 0)` to `(0, 0)`.

There are some implementation details to figure out. If you get stuck, I have found some implementations online: [on topcoder](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=572382&start=0&mc=17) and [on github](https://github.com/gcdart/PC-solutions/blob/master/Spoj/INUMBER.cpp).

Comment: Hi @IVlad: 
Thank you so much for you answer. I made a c++ solution based on your approach. However, it's still giving me a TLE. I 'd be glad if you can tell me where it may be getting a TLE.

** Edit: I'm keeping the track of the answer by using a string instead of back-tracking. **

Here's the link for my code: [link](http://ideone.com/KiBr82)

Comment: @user3811219 two issues stand out: 1. you are allocating memory for `vis` for every test case. Think about how you can avoid this; 2. Your `lngstr` function will slow everything down a lot because you will store every path. Think about how you can do it without strings. Reconstruct the answer like you would a path from `s` to `t` in standard BFS.