# Breadth First Traversal Algorithm

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

For a given n, I am trying to find the smallest number that is divisible by n, and also has sum of digits as n.

For example: For n = 10, Output should be 190, For n = 11, Output should be 209

I have adopted the Breadth First Traversal Approach to solve my problem.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <queue>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class State{
    public:
        int sum,rem;
        string str;
        State(int s,int r,string st){
            sum = s;
            rem = r;
            str = st;
        }
};

int main() {
    int n,newSum,newRem;
    queue<State> q;
    cin>>n;
    bool visited[n+1][n+1] = {0};
    State curr = State(0,0,"");
    q.push(curr);
    visited[0][0] = 1;
    while(!q.empty()){
        curr = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(curr.sum==n && curr.rem==0){
            cout<<curr.str<<endl;
            break;
        }
        for(int j=0; j<=9; j++){
            newSum = curr.sum + j;
            newRem = (curr.rem*10+j)%n;

            if(newSum > n){
                break;
            }

            else if(!visited[newSum][newRem]){
                curr = State(curr.sum+j, ((curr.rem*10)+j)%n,curr.str+to_string(j));
                q.push(curr);
                visited[newSum][newRem] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code, returns a number that satisfies the condition, but it is not the smallest possible number.
For n = 10, my code gives 12340
For n = 11, my code gives 1010207

Ideone link: http://ideone.com/c4W48N

Comment: As a note, jamming all your code into `main()` is usually the fastest way to making a tangled mess. Try and encapsulate your function neatly, then call it in `main()` using the absolute minimum amount of context. The variable names in here are too short to make any sense, so if you've got algorithmic problems you should be writing unit test code to verify it's working correctly rather than the old "compile and pray" approach.

Comment: I am trying to follow the approach mentioned in this answer<br/>http://stackoverflow.com/a/32426886/4822631

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try running through with a debugger, it shows up the problem very quickly.

In this line:

```
curr = State(curr.sum+j, ((curr.rem*10)+j)%n,curr.str+to_string(j));
q.push(curr);
```

You are assigning a new value to the `curr` variable, which you are then using next time around the loop. This means instead of trying 1, 2, 3, etc, you are trying 1, 12, 123, etc.

You are also recalculating items you have just calculated.

You can replace this with

```
State newState = State(newSum, newRem, curr.str + to_string(j));
q.push(newState);
```

or more simply again:

```
q.push(State(newSum, newRem, curr.str+to_string(j)));
```